# Remote Desktop access from ubuntu login screen

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, remote-access

I am new to ubuntu and i have a never before seen situation and didn't find any solution yet,
The issue is,

I have a sepate network for my internal devloper team, they works on ubuntu platform, internet is not accessible from this network.
some / all devlopers want to access internet for research and devlopment process and they don't want to switch (physically) on another desktop / machine.

Managment never allow internet access to my devloper networks machines and ask for alternet solution and must confirm that devloper not be able to transfer a single bit from their machine to internet machine.

I didn't find any solution yet, it may be a solution if i provide them a virtual machine (windows/ubuntu) for RDP (remote) access before there login. (after login they can make copy / paste etc.)

Comment: What you want is impossible. If they have internet access they can send and receive information.

Comment: thats why i want to provide them internet access on remote machine.

Comment: The level of trust your management has in devs is remarkable! Do you realize people can copy some of those bits in the memory inside their heads and afterwards reproduce those bits on internet-connected computer (or worse, at home)?